# How to store IBM DB2 schema objects in Versioning software

Tags: object, svn, db2, schema

I am using SVN (Subversion) which is a file versioning software, and stores the changes on code artifacts in the form of revisions.

I want to use the similar kind of software for DB2 objects like Tables and indexes, so that I can track changes over them using revisions.

Have anyone done this before?

Comment: Would you like to store the binary files of the DB2 itself store in SVN or would you like to store the SQL scripts which create the tables/indexes etc. in SVN?

Comment: Actually both. I would like to store the compelte schema definition, along with the script which creates it. Is there any tool which generates this kind of data for SVN/CVS

Comment: May be i misunderstand a thing, but if you have script(s) which creates everything (schema; sql tables; indexes etc.) isn't that enough? The problem with binary files you can't create diff from that which are usable. What kind of tools should generate what?

Comment: This is what i want - When a developer makes a change to table, then its corresponding  tablename.txt in repository should get committed, which would contain the complete table structure. Correspondingly, a separate DDL/DML_tablename.txt should get committed alongside tablename.txt. Since there are hundreds of schema objects, and dozens of types of them, I would have to extract them from DB2LOOK output after painstaking efforts. I want some tool to do this for me.

Comment: +1 for khoks, I create DDL/DML files to create tables/views and data.  You can version the text files and even tag them with versions in SVN

Answer (score 2):

You can use the IBM Data Studio client that creates a deployement group for database changes.

Once you create a deployement group, you can save it, and apply to several databases.

Take a look at
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dstudio/v3r2/topic/com.ibm.datatools.deployment.manager.ui.doc/topics/c_deploy_mgr.html

Comment: Thanks @AngocA, I am currently viewing the possibilities of integrating the data studio output with file versioning system. If the export format can be used to view revision changes in SVN, and for communicating changes amongst different deployment teams, then this might do the trick :).